# TestNG: Tests which are part of multiple groups are being excluded

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, grouping

I have few tests which are part of just one group (Smoke OR Regression) and few other tests which are part of multiple groups (Smoke AND Regression).

When I try to execute one group "Smoke" or "Regression", tests that are **only** part of either of those groups alone be executed and any tests that are part of multiple groups are being excluded even though they are also part of the specified group.

I have tried following options to execute Smoke and Regression group cases separately:

1. `mvn test -Dgroups=Smoke`
2. `mvn test -Dincludedgroups=Smoke`
3. `mvn test -Dexcludedgroups=Regression`
4. `mvn test -Dgroups=Regression`
5. `mvn test -Dincludedgroups=Regression`
6. `mvn test -Dexcludedgroups=Smoke`

---

**Test Methods:**

```
@Test(groups={"Smoke"})
public void One(){
 System.out.println("Smoke Test Message");
}

@Test(groups={"Smoke", "Regression"})
public void Two() {
 System.out.println("Smoke and Regression Test Message");       
}

@Test(groups={"Regression"})
public void Three() {
 System.out.println("Regression Test Message");     
}
```

---

**TestNG XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestNGSuite">
    <test name="GroupTests">
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.PageTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

- For options 1 to 3:

  - Expected: Methods One and Two should be executed
  - Actual: Method One alone be executed
- For options 4 to 6:

  - Expected: Methods Two and Three should be executed
  - Actual: Method Three alone be executed